# Delhi transfer from international terminal to domestic terminal

Tags: transit, india, international-travel, new-delhi, del

I am travelling from the USA to Delhi and 90 minutes later I need to catch another flight from Delhi to Chandigarh

What is the best way to reach to domestic airport so that I catch my flight in 90 minutes?

Comment: Is this one ticket?

Comment: yes one person...one ticket

Comment: @mealhour did you buy this as one ticket or separately?

Comment: it is a separate ticket

Comment: Which terminals?

Answer (score 3):

Delhi has 2 airports. Terminal 2 (T3)is where all international flights land.
Your domestic flight may leave from T3 or the domestic terminal 1D.

If it's different airports, there is no way you can make the transfer.

If it's the same airport, it's possible if your luggage is booked thru to the next destination and you have your boarding pass. Otherwise, it's difficult to make the transfer as the check-in counter for the domestic flight will close 45 minutes before departure (giving you a max of 45 minutes, assuming your flight is on time, to deplane, clear immigration, get your luggage, clear customs, go to the domestic counter, check-in and pass security.

Answer (score 0):

Delhi does have an International and Domestic airport in the same area. There are internal passage from the International Terminal to the Domestic Terminal. The airport authorities would help to transfer the luggage from one terminal to another.

Regarding 90 minutes, you can manage it within 15 minutes, along with the transfer of the luggage.

As you land to Delhi International airport T2, you can proceed to T3 terminal.